# Is there a method to input table a specific page?

Tags: floats, positioning

My paper is organized as follows:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{...}
\title{...}
\author{...}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{IEEEkeywords} ... \end{IEEEkeywords}
```

and then

```
\section{Introduction}
    ...
\section{Related work}
    ...
    \begin{table*}[!t]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{Comparison with related works}
    \label{table:relwor}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \hline
        \bfseries Reference & \bfseries ... & \bfseries ... & \bfseries ... & \bfseries ... & \bfseries ...\\
        \hline\hline
        \cite{...} & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
        \cite{...} & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
        ...
        ...
    \cite{...} & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
    Our work   & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\section{System model}
...
```

For a good reference numeric sorting, I had to put the table at the end of the related work section.
Thus, the table appears at the top of the 4th page.
However, I want for the table to appear at the top of the 2nd page.
Is there any method to put it at the top of the 2nd page?
Actually, if I put the codes regarding the table in front of the related work section, the table appears at the top of the 3rd page. (Surely, reference numbers get out of shape.)

Comment: `table*` spanning two columns always come at the earliest on the page after they appear in the source, so if you want it to appear on page two, place it earlier in the source, before page two starts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I place the table code there, the reference numbers are changed, so very look bad. That's my big issue.

Comment: if the table numbers get out of order, is it possible to input the table that should have the previous number before the full-width table?